# mask mail with Alternative words using php

Tags: php, email

Mentioned below is a dummy Email ID say,

```
abcdefghij@gmail.com
```

How to mask this  email ID partially using PHP?

Output i need as 
   `a*c*e*g*i*@gmail.com`

I have tried the below code, But it not works for below requirement

```
      $prop=3;
$domain = substr(strrchr($Member_Email, "@"), 1);
$mailname=str_replace($domain,'',$Member_Email);
$name_l=strlen($mailname);
$domain_l=strlen($domain);
    for($i=0;$i<=$name_l/$prop-1;$i++)
    {
    $start.='*';
    }

    for($i=0;$i<=$domain_l/$prop-1;$i++)
    {
    $end.='*';
    }

$MaskMail = substr_replace($mailname, $start,2, $name_l/$prop).substr_replace($domain, $end, 2, $domain_l/$prop);
```

Comment: How about encryption & decryption!

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this.

```
$delimeter = '@';
$mail_id = 'abcdefghij@gmail.com';
$domain = substr(strrchr($mail_id, $delimeter), 1);
$user_id = substr($mail_id,0,strpos($mail_id, $delimeter));
$string_array = str_split($user_id);

$partial_id = NULL;

foreach($string_array as $key => $val){

    if($key % 2 == 0){ 
        $partial_id .=$val;
    }else{
        $partial_id .='*' ;
    }

}
echo $partial_id.$delimeter.$domain;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail='abcdefghij@gmail.com';

$mail_first=explode('@',$mail);
$arr=str_split($mail_first[0]);
$mask=array();

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
    if($i%2!=0) {
        $arr[$i]='*';
    }

    $mask[]=$arr[$i];
}

$mask=join($mask).'@'.$mail_first[1];
echo $mask;
```

Result is :

```
a*c*e*g*i*@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *no loop* approach to replace every second character of an email username with a mask.

Custom PHP function using native functions `split`, `preg_replace` with regex `/(.)./`, and `implode`:

```
echo email_mask('abcdefghi@gmail.com');
// a*c*e*g*i*k*@gmail.com

function email_mask($email) {
    list($email_username, $email_domain) = split('@', $email);
    $masked_email_username = preg_replace('/(.)./', "$1*", $email_username);
    return implode('@', array($masked_email_username, $email_domain));
}
```

*Regex Explanation:*

The regular expression starts at the beginning of the string, matches 2 characters and captures the first of those two, replaces the match with the first character followed by an asterisk `*`. `preg_replace` repeats this throughout the remaining string until it can no longer match a pair of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to have that many asterisks?
It's so hard to read that way.

I will suggest you keep things simple.
Maybe something like this is enough
https://github.com/fedmich/PHP_Codes/blob/master/mask_email.php

Masks an email to show first 3 characters and then the last character before the @ sign

ABCDEFZ@gmail.com becomes
A*****Z@gmail.com

Here is the full code that is also in that Github link

```
function mask_email( $email ) {
    /*
    Author: Fed
    Simple way of masking emails
    */

    $char_shown = 3;

    $mail_parts = explode("@", $email);
    $username = $mail_parts[0];
    $len = strlen( $username );

    if( $len <= $char_shown ){
        return implode("@", $mail_parts );  
    }

    //Logic: show asterisk in middle, but also show the last character before @
    $mail_parts[0] = substr( $username, 0 , $char_shown )
        . str_repeat("*", $len - $char_shown - 1 )
        . substr( $username, $len - $char_shown + 2 , 1  )
        ;

    return implode("@", $mail_parts );
}
```